# strtotime 7 days ago, the entire 24 hour day

Tags: php, datetime, time, strtotime

I need to be able to create two time points:

1. 7 days ago from today, beginning of the day (12:00am)
2. 7 days ago from today, end of the day (11:59pm)

I started it, but it's not producing what I need:

```
$starting_time = new DateTime('today');
$starting_time->modify('-7 day -1 second');

$ending_time = new DateTime('today');
$ending_time->modify('-8 day -1 second');
```

And I need them both to be a fully formatted timestamp: **2015:07:14 15:51:12**

The end goal is to be able to execute a SQL query to check for dates that land within that 24 hour day, like so:

```
whereBetween('mytable.expiry_date', array($starting_time, $ending_time))
```

Comment: that's racey code. consider what happens running `$start_time` at 11:59:59pm, and `$end_time` at 12:00:00am. generate **ONE** "today" value, and the modify it as needed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. I'm needing these two values so I can run a SQL query, checking for dates within that time period.

Comment: then don't do that at all. `select ... where date(yourfield) = '2015-07-14'`, using your db's usual date/time functions for this.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you're understanding what I need. See my modified question. I just want the two dates as reference, nothing more.

Comment: HI try setting the time using setTime() such as http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php

Comment: Define "day". What if there's a Daylight Saving change in the interval?

Comment: It's usually a better idea to use half-open intervals.  In other words, have both start and end be 00:00, then compare with `start <= value < end`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$start = new DateTime();
$start->setTime(0,0,1); 
$end = clone $start;  // or just make new DateTime;
$end->modify( '-7 day' );
$start->setTime(23,59,59);
```

But as others have noted when querying the DB you should just use the DATE() function, it's simpler, more robust, and easier to read and understand the intent of the code later.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment request:

consider what happens if you run your two `new Date()` right around a daychange:

```
11:59:59pm -> new Date('today') -> $start = Jul 20, 2015 11:59:59pm
12:00:02am -> new Date('today') -> $end   = Jul 21, 2015 12:00:02am

$start -> -7 days -1 second -> Jul 13, 2015 11:59:58pm
$end ->   -8 days -1 second -> Jul 13, 2015 12:00:01am
```

"oops".

somewhat contrived example, but never ever assume that 'today' will remain constant in a program.

Comment: Thanks for this Marc. Let me take a look and see if this is indeed what I need :)

Comment: there's no need to have php generate dates for you, unless you have extremely specific needs. mysql and most other DBs have all kinds of date/time functions for this sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the date 7 days ago and append 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 to it.

Like

$start_time = $date_7days_ago. "00:00:00";
$end_time = $date_7days_ago."23:59:59";

This will work complete fine with the query you are looking at.